# Calculating outcomes in IPTW

Tags: r, propensity-scores, weighted-regression, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I have a few questions concerning what to do next after balancing your population with IPTW.

This is a code just to have an example:

```
library(WeightIt)
W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                      data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")
```

Outcome = `re78`

**First**, if I want to calculate the odds ratio (e.g. odds of re78 in treated vs non-treated), I write the following formula:

```
d.w <- svydesign(~1, weights = W.out$weights, data = lalonde)
fit <- svyglm(re78 ~ treat, design = d.w)
```

My questions are:

1. "Treat" itself doesn't have a weight since patients have been grouped by the presence or absence of treatment. How does the formula use the weights that I have provided?
2. Why does the result change if I write: `fit <- svyglm(re78 ~ treat + age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75, design = d.w)`. Shouldn't this variables already been accounted for if the "weights" are considered when I write just "treat"? (as I said in question 1)
3. In some papers I saw that there is a "weighted rate" for the outcomes stratified by treatment. For example, at the end of the IPTW table there is a weighted rate for death (which is the outcome) in treated patients and non-treated. Of course death has not been balanced so how is this possible? Where do these weights come from? Does it make sense to put it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weights are not applied to individual variables. They are applied to the whole sample once estimated. So question 1 doesn't make sense. Instead of using `svyglm()`, let's use `lm()`, which has a simpler interface. Running `lm(Y ~ treat, data = data, weights = weights)`, which fits a weighted least squares regression, and looking at the coefficient on `treat` is the same as computing the weighted difference in outcome means

```r
with(data, 
  weighted.mean(Y[treat == 1], weights[treat == 1]) - 
    weighted.mean(Y[treat == 0], weights[treat == 0]))
```

They are two ways of doing the same thing. This is called the Hajek estimator of the treatment effect. We use the former because it is more straightforward to compute standard errors. Using `svyglm()` does the same thing but uses a different interface. (Note the standard errors from `lm()` are incorrect and need to be adjusted, but the ones from `svyglm()` are approximately correct.)

In question 2, you ask why we would further adjust for covariates after weighting and why the estimate changes. We further adjust for covariates for two reasons: 1) to reduce bias due to remaining imbalance, i.e., when the weights don't exactly balance the covariate means, which is always the case for standard IPTW (but not for all method like entropy balancing, which does perfectly balance the means), and 2) to increase the precision of the effect estimate (decrease the standard error) by explaining variability in the outcome. If you exactly balance your covariate means, then it doesn't matter whether you include covariates in the outcome model or not; the estimate will be the same, which is demonstrated in [Hainmueller (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpr025) who proposes entropy balancing.

For question 3, a rate is a mean. It is the frequency divided by the sample size. We can compute a weighted rate for a binary variable by computing the weighted mean of that variable. It doesn't matter whether the weights were designed to balance a variable or not, you can still compute a weighted mean using those weights. That is, to compute the weighted death rate under control in the weighted sample, you just run

```r
with(data,
  weighted.mean(Y[treat == 0], weights[treat == 0]))
```

This is also equal to the intercept in the weighted least squares model for the outcome when no covariates are included. So the weights are the IPTW weights, the only weights that are being estimated.

---

It might be that the ease of using the software is obfuscating some of the details for you. I recommend doing everything manually so you understand what each step is actually doing. For example, estimate the propensity scores (PS) manually:

```r
ps.fit <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + married + re74, data = lalonde,
              family = binomial)
ps <- ps.fit$fitted.values
```

You can see we get one PS for each unit. Now, compute the IPTW ATT weights from the PS using the formula:

```r
weights <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1, 1, ps / (1 - ps))
```

You can see we get one weights for each unit. Hopefully this makes it clear the we don't have weights for variables; we have one weight for each unit, and this set of weights balances the covariates and is used in the outcome model to estimate the treatment effect. The reason we use it in the outcome model is *because* it balances the covariates.

We can assess balance using the weights by computing the weighted difference in proportion or the standardized mean difference after weighting:

```r
# Weighted difference in proportion for `married`
with(lalonde,
  weighted.mean(married[treat == 1], weights[treat == 1]) -
    weighted.mean(married[treat == 0], weights[treat == 0]))

# Weighted SMD for `age`
with(lalonde,
  (weighted.mean(age[treat == 1], weights[treat == 1]) -
     weighted.mean(age[treat == 0], weights[treat == 0])) /
       sd(age[treat == 1]))
```

You should see that these align with the `bal.tab()` output.

Finally, if balance is acceptable, we can computed the weighted outcome means and their difference or use `lm()` or `svyglm()` to estimate the treatment effect as a coefficient in the outcome regression model:

```r
# Weighted outcome mean under control
m0 <- with(lalonde, weighted.mean(re78[treat == 0], weights[treat == 0]))

# Weighted outcome mean under treatment
m1 <- with(lalonde, weighted.mean(re78[treat == 1], weights[treat == 1]))

# Difference in weighted means: the treatment effect estimate
m1 - m0

# Using linear regression to estimate treatment effect
lm(re78 ~ treat, data = lalonde, weights = weights) |>
  coef()
```

The first step of estimating the propensity scores and weights is done by `weightit()`, and the second step is done by `bal.tab()`. But it is important to run these analyses yourself manually to understand where these values are coming from. Hopefully that elucidates the method for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an excellent answer and exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to know where everything comes from and you explained it perfectly. Thank you very much! :)